# How to store the username in database under GDPR?

Tags: database

This is **not** a duplicate of [How to handle emails as usernames under GDPR?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184519/how-to-handle-emails-as-usernames-under-gdpr) because my question is related with performance.

I have an application that I want to make comply with GDPR.

My strategy for storing personal information is to encrypt it, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to handle usernames.

I have been searching for other questions, like [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184519/how-to-handle-emails-as-usernames-under-gdpr), but I can't find any with the same problem I have.

My question is related to how I should store and validate the username in the database.

The approach I was thinking of is to have three columns:

1. username_encrypted (encryption key will be outside the database and database will not have access to it)
2. salt
3. username_hash: hash(username+salt)

When I want to retrieve the username in plain text, I get the username_encrypted and I decrypt it.

When I want to validate the username, for each user in database, I must **Option 1**:

1. Compute the hash using the user salt (the salt is different for each user) (hash(username+salt))
2. Compare the result of the previous point with the username_hash column

**So, my question is:** Is there another way to achieve the same goal without computing the hash of all users? For a smaller database this may not be a problem. But for a bigger database this can have a big impact.

If it's relevant, the database I am using is PostgreSQL.

Validate the username **Option 2** (see Nosajimiki answer/comment below):

1. Have a global salt for all users and the column username_hash is computed with the global salt
2. Compute the hash (hash(username+global_salt))
3. Compare the result of previous line with column username_hash

Comment: I don't think usernames are to be encrypted by GDPR...

Comment: An username my contain personal information. It is possible to create an username with your first and last name.

Comment: @bruno.almeida True, but if you are explicit about the username being exposed, people can choose whether to provide an identifiable string, or something else - this is commonly used for display names which are distinct from usernames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle emails as usernames under GDPR?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184519/how-to-handle-emails-as-usernames-under-gdpr)

Comment: @Matthew, in this case only administrator choose the username. An they will choose something like first and last name. So is a requirement to protect this information in database.

Comment: @ThoriumBR, no is different. My question is related with performance.

Comment: Provide the salt to the user, then the user answers with hash(username+salt). Do not do it with the password.

Comment: @A.Hersean, it is not feasible because, for the user to decorate it, it will have to be a weak salt. Also, for authentication, user will have to give three inputs instead of two.

Comment: Even without the linked answer saying "encryption isn't always required", the default level of encryption is probably going to be at-rest.  When dealing with a database and access controls, your best bet is probably to restrict classes of users from accessing those columns (admins probably need access).  Otherwise, display vs login name is okay (although please, allow people to make them the same, and to **change** them), and be clear about which is displayed.  After that... you can't protect people from their own stupidity.

Comment: If your question is about performance, then it is not about GDPR and it is not about security.

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate that the username is supplied by an admin. That alone raises several follow-up questions. As a GDPR expert, I'm not clear why you need to do any of these things.

Comment: If his real question was "do I need to do this for GDPR?", then it's a legal question.  If it's "How to encrypt usernames at rest", then it is an Information Security question.  Either way, stackOverflow is probably not better suited for this question than Information Security was because it requires deep understanding of encryption which is not necessarily a programming issue, and there is no actual code or even programming language in the question he is trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it a lot like a password.  A login name when hashed with a site-wide salt can be checked by much like a password; you just need to verify it, you don't need to query it.

This is not the best practice for password storage per say since you will often find a lot of people using the same passwords, but for usernames, a site-wide salt should not expose any extra vulnerability since they should all be unique.

If you need to display the username after logging in.  To do this, you could save the username a person types into a logon form as a session variable before you hash it.  This way the Session remembers you are JohnSmith101 for as long as you are logged in, but the database only ever knows your hash.

Comment: ...the problem with this is that, yes, you _do_ need to query the username, if it's being used for login.  Otherwise, you have no idea which user it actually belongs to - and what other data they have access to.  Which means, if the scheme is similar to passwords, hashing it for every user queried.  This is a problem on even small databases, given the standard that hashes be "slow", and quite impossible on databases of any real size.

Comment: The problem is not for every request, but at the login. Actually, to check the password i get the user row based on username. Then i hash the password and i compare it. But now i can not directly get the user row, because the username column is encrypted/hashed. To compare, i need to hash with the salt of all users or decrypt all username_encrypted

Comment: Just invert the order.  Hash the username, then do a search for that. SO you don't search for JohnSmith123, you search for 78a6dc32...

Comment: @Nosajimiki, but the hash is created with a different salt for each user. So i must try to hash with all salt, to find the right hash. If there is no other alternative, that is what i will do. But my question is to find an alternative to that.

Comment: Oh yes, you would need a standard, site-wide salt.  It's really not "best practice" to do that for passwords, but the only reason unique salts are more secure than a site-wide salt is because they prevent a single test from revealing more than one cracked password.  Since usernames are unique, it does not matter (for any reasons that I know of) if you salt them individually or not.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, interesting point of view. going to wait to see if anyone have other ideas.